# Ext.net grid panel column SetHidden doesn't work (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext.net

I have view and it contains a simple grid panel:

```
@(Html.X().GridPanel()
    .Width(600)
    .Height(350)
    //...
    .ColumnModel(
        Html.X().DataIndex("1").BooleanColumn().Text("Boolean").SetHidden(true),
        Html.X().DataIndex("2").Column().Editor(Html.X().TextField()).Text("Name"),
        Html.X().DataIndex("3").DateColumn().Editor(Html.X().DateField()).Text("Date"),
        Html.X().DataIndex("4").NumberColumn().Editor(Html.X().NumberField()).Text("Number").Format("0.00")
    )
```

)

but SetHidden(true) doesnt work: https://gyazo.com/7ba7cbae19d786a99a750544726cf6ee

How can i change the visibility of a column in view?

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.X().DataIndex("1").BooleanColumn().Text("Boolean").Hidden(true)
```

please try this